# Allow user to press two Gui.button at the same time in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

For example: "I create 2 button, one for character to move foward and one for character to jump".

Problem is: when press that two button only one of them can work.

So can anyone tell me how to make that 2 button work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be replacing your 2 GUI buttons to GUI Textures. Textures are placed in a Rect so in your update you have to check if your "touch" event is within one of these positions.

Have a look at:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/380681/multiple-guibuttons-at-the-same-time.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/585943/multi-touch-gui-buttons.html

They might help!

Comment: Thanks EoD, your answer is really helpful